# objective-c の performSelector を使用したランダムなメソッドの呼び出しについて

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

performSelectorに、NSArrayで生成したランダムなメソッド（文字列）を代入し、そのメソッドに飛ばすにはどうすればよいでしょうか？下記のソースだとクラッシュします。

```
- (void)trigger:(id)sender{
NSArray *tone_array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"method_1",@"method_2",@"method_3",@"method_4",nil];

    uint32_t rnd = (int)arc4random_uniform((int)[tone_array count]);
    NSString *rndMethod = [tone_array objectAtIndex:rnd];

    [self performSelector:@selector(rndMethod:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];}

- (void)method_1:(id)sender{

//処理するアクション

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perfomSelector`の前に`NSSelectorFromString(メソッド名文字列)`を実行して、`SEL`型の変数に戻り値を代入して使います。

以下は、ボタンを押すと画面上の`calledMethodNameField`と言う名前で`IBOutlet`を繋いだ`label`に呼ばれた文字列と同じ名前のメソッドを呼び出して、ラベルにメソッドの名前を表示してみせるサンプルです。

```
    SEL currentSelector = NSSelectorFromString(currentMethodName);
    [self performSelector:currentSelector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

上の２行がキモになります。

```
- (IBAction)testButtonPressed:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSArray<NSString *> *selectorNames = @[@"method1:", @"method2:", @"method2:", @"method3:", @"method4:"];
    NSUInteger rnd = arc4random_uniform((int)selectorNames.count);

    NSString *currentMethodName = selectorNames[rnd];
    SEL currentSelector = NSSelectorFromString(currentMethodName);

    [self performSelector:currentSelector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void) method1:(id) sender
{
    calledMethodNameField.stringValue = @"method1";
}

- (void) method2:(id) sender
{
    calledMethodNameField.stringValue = @"method2";
}

- (void) method3:(id) sender
{
    calledMethodNameField.stringValue = @"method3";
}

- (void) method4:(id) sender
{
    calledMethodNameField.stringValue = @"method4";
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！でも、下記のように私の環境で置き換えたらエラーとなりました。。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！メソッドの部分が- (void) method1:(id)sender{ 処理}としているのですが、この場合エラーになります。。処理はmp3を再生させることです。どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `- (void) method1:(id)sender`の場合は、配列に入れるメソッド名を`:`で終わる様にすれば大丈夫です。

Comment: できました！いつもありがとうございます。

Comment: おめでとうございます。よろしければ回答の左、数字と上下に▲の下の✓マークをクリックして有効な回答であるマークを付けてもらえると、この質問に有効な回答がある事が一覧から見取りやすいのでお願いします